# -[NSCFSet invalidate]: unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
*** -[NSCFSet invalidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4726190

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFSet invalidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4726190'

Stack: (
    40895051,
    2477298953,
    41166651,
    40629526,
    40626194,
    23371,
    2792390,
    3262677,
    3271439,
    3266626,
    2915688,
    2810349,
    2841671,
    49254780,
    40435772,
    40431688,
    49248413,
    49248610,
    2833889,
    9956,
    9810
)
```

How to rectify this problem?

Comment: my God how do you expect people to help you without any code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your NSTimer instance or something was already released. You should be sure to retain your instance for calling method of it.